# SQL Invalid data is showing

Tags: sql-server

```
t0212_1   t0212_2
884999999 GCP-9     Company A
8849999   GCP-7     Company B

@val = 884999999
```

Here's my query :

```
Select * Company
WHERE t0212_1= (LEFT(CONVERT(BIGINT,@val),convert(int,substring('GCP-9',5,2)))) OR
      t0212_1= LEFT(CONVERT(BIGINT,@val),convert(int,substring('GCP-7',5,2)))
```

When I searched 8849999   , 8849999 shows(this is RIGHT).

When I searched 884999999 , 884999999 shows(this is RIGHT) and 8849999 shows(WRONG).

What to do, please help

Thanks,
If you dont understand my very short explanation you can verify it to me.

Comment: Can you at least try to format your question? It's pretty much unreadable right now.

Comment: can you check it again please

Comment: convert(int,substring('GCP-9',5,2)) means i am only need to get 9 digit because this stored procedure is accepting 884999999 +(check digits) = 8849999990002, My problem is it also involved 8849999(the 7 digit which is almost a like to 884999999)

Comment: shrib.com/h4QYC4H5okZKqO0 HERES MY sp

Answer (score 0):

Your filteration is either 7 or 9 characters from the input (DECLARE @val INT = 884999999)
should match the column (t0212_1) value.

As per your filter, you would get two records since the two records matched on your filteration.

You can use this SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM @Company
WHERE t0212_1 = (LEFT(CONVERT(BIGINT, @val), convert(INT, substring(t0212_2, 5, 2))))
```

Comment: https://shrib.com/h4QYC4H5okZKqO0 , heres the link of my stored procedure , i am using method "GTIN"